# malloc(): memory corruption

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

Here is the simplified program that I think can lead to this error.

```
char *p = (char*)malloc(8192);
for(int i = 0; i < 9200; ++i){
  p[i] = '1';
}
char *s = (char*)malloc(strlen(p));
```

The original project is rather complicated, so I simplified it. I assigned 8192 bytes using malloc. Then my program will write more than 8192 characters in to the array. Then I will allocate memory using malloc.

This mini program didn't crash. But in the original big project, it crashes with this error:

> malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000007d20bd0 ***

What may cause this difference?

Comment: You've allocated 8192 bytes, but try to write to 9200 bytes. How does this make sense? How about you try to not do that, and memory won't be corrupted? :)

Comment: Do I see this right? You allocate 8kB of memory but actually write 9200 Bytes into it? How is that supposed to fit?

Comment: Yes, I know this is not right. But I just want to know the hidden mechanism.@InternetAussie@Psi

Comment: Besides trying to write to memory which you have not allocated, after your for loop, `p` now points to the byte immediately after the last `1` you wrote. That means that `strlen(p)` is not going to return anything meaningful.

Comment: "*What may cause this difference?*" undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Corrected@Wilson

Comment: `strlen()` will fail (lead to undefined behaviour)  in *any* case as no `0`-terminator had been written.

Comment: Also in C there is ***no*** need to cast the result of `malloc()`& friends.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What may cause this difference?

Basically, the memory allocator allocates *pages* of memory at once for use by programs, and it gives you a pointer within them (making sure the following space is free for use). Since these pages are usually bigger than 8KiB, you have no issue in your mini-program. But if a larger program is allocating larger amounts of memory and writing further and further past the end of your allocated space, then you'll end up attempting to write into unallocated memory (or memory used by another program!), thus corrupting memory.

Comment: `char *p = (char*)malloc(8192);
for(int i = 0; i < 9200; ++i){
  p[i] = '1';
}` this should also behave unexceptionally??

Comment: Not necessarily. So long as the memory beyond your allocated space is for your process and is unused, then it's "fine". But there is no way of knowing without digging into the OS's memory allocations, so try to stop yourself from accessing memory beyond your allocated space. That code can certainly corrupt memory too; the `malloc` result just needs to be in the right place.

Comment: Writing to another processe's memory in user space is not really something you'll be doing in about any modern OS on top of a CPU with an MMU, barring explicitly shared memory, but usually if that is the case, you *want* to write to "memory used by another program".

Comment: Do operating systems have ways of correcting corrupted memory?

Answer (score 16):

It is **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** because you have allocated `8192` bytes memory but you are trying to write `9200` bytes. Which is out of bound.

Comment: I know, but what kind of undefined behavior?@rsp

Comment: There's no such thing as different kinds of undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Could please list some examples of undefined behavior?@willys

Comment: @YuanWen: Many cases invoking Undefined Behaviour are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior#t=20170424105058111517

Comment: @YuanWen this is not how C language work. you cant write to memory location that don't belong to your code else it will crash.

Comment: @rootTraveller: there is no need at *all* for the code to crash ... again: undefined behaviour is undefined. I've seen such code which ran in Production for years ... :-(

Comment: @YuanWen undefined behaviour means anything can happen. Your program might crash, it might work, it might introduce subtle data corruption, it might format your hard disk. With suitable hardware attached, it might create Skynet and commence on the extermination of human kind.

Answer (score 2):

Writing to memory which you have not allocated is undefined behaviour. That's because `malloc()` returns a section of memory which you may write to, so when you write past the end of that region, you are overwriting something which is not yours.

That could be a structure used by malloc itself, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of luck. Your operating system may reserve memory more than the 8kB you requested. Also what you have reserved before and after may have an effect on the behaviour.

It is not said that your program will crash on buffer overflow. In fact the behaviour is undefined or implementation defined.